# shift/reduce conflicts while writing rule to resolve nested preprocessor inside a structure.How to resolve this?

Tags: bison, yacc

This gives 66 shift/reduce conflicts

```
initializer
    : '{' initializer_list '}'           
    | '{' initializer_list ',' '}'            
    | '{' preprocessor_list  initializer_list    '}'    
    ;
preprocessor_list
    : preprocessor
    | preprocessor_list preprocessor
    ;
```

but this works:

```
initializer
    : '{' initializer_list '}'       
    | '{' initializer_list ',' '}'     
    | '{' preprocessor initializer_list '}'    
    | '{' preprocessor preprocessor initializer_list '}    
    | '{' preprocessor preprocessor  preprocessor  initializer_list '}'
    ;
```

Please find below the definition of initializer list:

```
initializer_list
    : designation initializer
    | preprocessor
    | preprocessor initializer_list ','
    | preprocessor initializer_list ','  preprocessor_list
    | initializer_list ',' preprocessor_list designation initializer
    | initializer_list ','  designation initializer
    | initializer_list ',' initializer
    ;

designation
    : designator_list '='
    ;
designator_list
    : designator
    | designator_list designator
    ;

designator
    : '[' constant_expression ']'
    | '.' IDENTIFIER
    ;
```

Rules for preprocessor:

```
preprocessor
    : hash_define BLACK_SPACE define_expression
    | hash_else NEW_LINE
    | hash_if BLACK_SPACE unary_expression NEW_LINE
    | hash_ifdef BLACK_SPACE unary_expression NEW_LINE
    | hash_ifndef BLACK_SPACE unary_expression NEW_LINE
    | hash_ident BLACK_SPACE STRING_LITERAL NEW_LINE
    | hash_include STRING_LITERAL 
                 {printf("string identified in #include\n");}
      NEW_LINE   {printf("#include with quotes\n");}
    | hash_include '<' filepath  '>' NEW_LINE
    | hash_line BLACK_SPACE I_CONSTANT NEW_LINE
    | hash_line BLACK_SPACE I_CONSTANT {enable_space = 1;}
                BLACK_SPACE STRING_LITERAL NEW_LINE
    | hash_undef BLACK_SPACE IDENTIFIER NEW_LINE
    | hash_LINK BLACK_SPACE STRING_LITERAL NEW_LINE
    | hash_endif NEW_LINE
    ;
```

Comment: Difficult to answer without seeing the definitions of preprocessor and initializer-list, but your first excerpt has two consecutive colons after initializer, which is a syntax error.

Comment: consecutive colon was a copy paste error(removed).I have added rules for initializer_list and its successors.Also added rule for preprocessor.

Comment: It would be useful if you could learn how to format code blocks in questions. (It's easy: indent every line four spaces. You can use the `ctl-K` shortcut, too.)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `initializer_list` can start with `preprocessor`. That makes this fragment of `initializer`

```
`preprocessor_list initializer_list`
```

ambiguous since any `preprocessor` expansions could belong to either the `preprocessor_list` in `initializer` or to `initializer_list`. So pick one of the `initializer` and `initializer_list` to include the leading `preprocessor`s.